# Update 10.0 to 10.1

Tags: mariadb, centos7

What is the procedure for safe use of version 10.0 to 10.1 MariaDB?
I tried to locate a manual for this update and did not find any information or someone who did.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I am fraid that your question is off topic here. For more information, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB has official instructions [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/upgrading-from-mariadb-100-to-101/).

In case of Ubuntu 14.04, I just had to change

```
deb http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main
```

to

```
deb http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu trusty main
```

in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```